# Emberjs loadInitializer error

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Not sure how to correct this error.  I'm following along with this screencast https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLXGKNA4P_g and it appears that the update to Ember breaks functionality.

```
DEPRECATION: `lookup` was called on a Registry. The `initializer` API 
no longer receives a container, and you should use an `instanceInitializer` to look up objects from the container. 
See http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations#toc_deprecate-access-to-
instances-in-initializers for more details.
```

I'm new to Ember and have found the https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3051 thread on github but I'm not quite sure how to fix this.  This is my app.js file

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Resolver from 'ember/resolver';
import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers';
import config from './config/environment';

var App;

Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true;

App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
  Resolver: Resolver
});

loadInitializers(App, config.modulePrefix);

export default App;
```

Can someone explain how to make this compliant with the error?  The documentation suggests this:

```
http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_deprecate-access-to-instances-in-initializers
```

But being new to Ember, I'm not sure what this means or how to implement it.

Comment: As in the GitHub issue you mentioned in your post, this deprecation warning will go away after [this commit lands](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3136). Meanwhile you can just ignore the warning.

Comment: Thank you.  Didn't know it handed landed yet.